# Rearranging a set of numbers

Tags: list-manipulation

I have this set of numbers, that is a range of prices (ie 6-10) and a quantity of products (5)

```
6 - 10:   5
11 - 15:   8
16 - 20:   15
36 - 40:   63
41 - 45:  1
46 - 50:  1
51 - 55:  5
56 - 60:  3
61 - 65:  140
66 - 70:  120
71 - 75:  95
86 - 90:  2
91 - 95:  2
96 - 100:  12
101 - 200:  150
201 - 300:  300
301 - 400:  1
401 - 500:  1
501 - 600:  1
601 - 700:  1
1201 - 1300: 1
1301 - 1400: 1
```

And I want to obtain ranges like this ones

```
0 - 60:  111
61 - 65:  140
66 - 70: 120
71 - 100:  111
101 - 200: 150
201 - 300: 300
301 - 1400 : 6
```

The idea is to obtain less ranges, with similar quantities (grouping the original ones).

Is there any way to do this for any set of ranges? 
How can I handle the deviation when one number is too high?

Comment: By what measure or specification are the output ranges determined?  Do you give them explicitly, or are they to be selected automatically?

Comment: Also, how is your data structured? Is it imported from a file? Is it stored as strings? Or can the above be entered (or is available) in a _Mathematica_ friendly data structure (i.e., without having to do unnecessary manipulations)?

Answer (score 3):

Let's start with an easier to work with data format:

```
data =
{{6, 10, 5}, {11, 15, 8}, {16, 20, 15}, {36, 40, 63}, {41, 45, 1}, {46, 50, 1},
 {51, 55, 5}, {56, 60, 3}, {61, 65, 140}, {66, 70, 120}, {71, 75, 95},
 {86, 90, 2}, {91, 95, 2}, {96, 100, 12}, {101, 200, 150}, {201, 300, 300},
 {301, 400, 1}, {401, 500, 1}, {501, 600, 1}, {601, 700, 1}, {1201, 1300, 1}, {1301, 1400, 1}};
```

Given this data, and certain assumptions about your goals, you might use something like this:

```
f[0, {s2_, e2_, t2_}] := {s2, e2, t2}

f[{s1_, e1_, t1_}, {s2_, e2_, t2_}] :=
 With[{new = {s1, e2, t1 + t2}},
  If[Last@new < 100, new, Sow[new]; 0]
 ]

Append[#2[[1]], #] & @@ Reap[Fold[f, 0, data]]
```

> ```
> {{6, 60, 101}, {61, 70, 260}, {71, 100, 111}, {101, 300, 450}, {301, 1400, 6}}
> ```

Comment: Another option is to use `{Interval[...], count}` as the structure, and take their union to combine consecutive intervals. I don't have time to work on this, but someone can pick it up if it's viable.

Comment: @rm-rf I see.  One would need to account for the "gap" i.e. union `{1, 4}` and `{5, 8}` would be `Interval[{1, 4}, {5, 8}]`.

Comment: Ah, yes... didn't realize OP had discontinuous intervals. Never mind then; will probably be more work than necessary

Answer (score 2):

Using Mr.Wizard's `¡EZ-Data!` product, here's one approach that takes advantage of the built-in `Interval` functionality:

```
data = {{6, 10, 5}, {11, 15, 8}, {16, 20, 15}, {36, 40, 63}, {41, 45, 1}, {46, 50, 1},
 {51, 55, 5}, {56, 60, 3}, {61, 65, 140}, {66, 70, 120}, {71, 75, 95}, {86, 90, 2},
 {91, 95, 2}, {96, 100, 12}, {101, 200, 150}, {201, 300, 300}, {301, 400, 1},
 {401, 500, 1}, {501, 600, 1}, {601, 700, 1}, {1201, 1300, 1}, {1301, 1400, 1}};

curated = Interval[{#1, #2}] -> #3 & @@@ data;
$$range[rng_] := Select[curated, IntervalMemberQ[Interval[rng], First[#]] &];
$$total[rng_] := Total[Last /@ $$range[rng]];

$$total[{6, 60}]
```

101

Also:

```
partition[list_, n_] := Partition[list, n, n, {1, 1}, {}];
partitioned = partition[Sort[curated], 3];
grouped = IntervalUnion[Sequence @@ First /@ #] -> Total[Last /@ #] & /@ partitioned;
Column[grouped]

(* output *)
Interval[{6, 10}, {11, 15}, {16, 20}] -> 28
Interval[{36, 40}, {41, 45}, {46, 50}] -> 65
Interval[{51, 55}, {56, 60}, {61, 65}] -> 148
Interval[{66, 70}, {71, 75}, {86, 90}] -> 217
Interval[{91, 95}, {96, 100}, {101, 200}] -> 164
Interval[{201, 300}, {301, 400}, {401, 500}] -> 302
Interval[{501, 600}, {601, 700}, {1201, 1300}] -> 3
Interval[{1301, 1400}] -> 1
```

You could of course collapse those intervals (e.g. `Interval[is__] :> Interval[{First@First[{is}], Last@Last[{is}]}]`). Note the `Sort`. It's not necessarily needed here, but the point is `Interval`s have an ordering that makes this sort of thing easier in the general case. (And note that `Interval` isn't really needed in this last code snippet.)

Answer (score 0):

This is not the prettiest code but anyway...

`group[data, m]` accumulates the quantity values and rounds them down to the nearest multiple of `m` to collect the intervals into groups.

`grouping[data, n]` runs `group` on the data with a range of `m` values from 70% of `n` to 130% of `n`. It then selects the result with the lowest "error" value (where the error is defined as `Total[(quantities - n)^2`

```
group[data_, m_] := {#[[1, 1]], #[[-1, 2]], Total@#[[All, 3]]} & /@ 
  SplitBy[Join[data, Accumulate[data[[All, {-1}]]], 2], Floor[Last[#], m] &]

grouping[data_, n_] := 
 First@SortBy[group[data, #] & /@ Range[Round[0.7 n], Round[1.3 n]], 
   Total[(#[[All, -1]] - n)^2] &]
```

Examples using Mr. Wizard's data:

```
grouping[data, 100]
(* {{6, 60, 101}, {61, 65, 140}, {66, 70, 120}, {71, 100, 111}, {101, 200, 150}, {201, 1400, 306}} *)

grouping[data, 200]
(* {{6, 65, 241}, {66, 100, 231}, {101, 200, 150}, {201, 1400, 306}} *)

grouping[data, 300]
(* {{6, 70, 361}, {71, 200, 261}, {201, 1400, 306}} *)
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks neat and easy to understand, IMHO:

```
data = {{6, 10, 5}, {11, 15, 8}, {16, 20, 15}, {36, 40, 63}, {41, 45, 
1}, {46, 50, 1}, {51, 55, 5}, {56, 60, 3}, {61, 65, 140}, {66, 70,
 120}, {71, 75, 95}, {86, 90, 2}, {91, 95, 2}, {96, 100, 
12}, {101, 200, 150}, {201, 300, 300}, {301, 400, 1}, {401, 500, 
1}, {501, 600, 1}, {601, 700, 1}, {1201, 1300, 1}, {1301, 1400, 
1}};

 With[{thresh = 100}, 
 data //. {p : {{_, _, _}} ...,  {s1_, e1_, t1_}, {s2_, e2_, t2_}, 
    rest___} :> 
   If[t1 + t2 < thresh, {p, {s1, e2, t1 + t2}, 
     rest}, {p, {{s1, e2, t1 + t2}}, rest}]]

(* {{{6, 60, 101}}, {{61, 70, 260}}, {{71, 100, 111}}, {{101, 300, 
   450}}, {301, 1400, 6}} *)
```

Edit: I just realised that each element of the output list is list of list of integers, except the last one which might possibly remain a list of integers, but that's easily rectified with `Level`:

```
Level[%, {-2}]


(* {{6, 60, 101}, {61, 70, 260}, {71, 100, 111}, {101, 300, 450}, {301, 
  1400, 6}} *)
```